# How to Get all Knowledge Article Types?

Tags: knowledge, articles

I am trying to create a VF page to pull all knowledge articles with few custom fields.
We have 10 article types in our org. 
As per salesforce documentation I need to query on each article type object to get knowledge articles of that particular article type as :

```
SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId, Title, PublishStatus, Isdeleted 
                             FROM Help_Center__kav WHERE 
                             language = 'en_US' 
                             AND publishStatus = 'Online'
```

So if I have 10 article types (or more) do we need to make 10 SOQL Queries?
If one more article type is added, I will have to change my apex logic.

1. Could anyone suggest a better approach?
2. Is there a way I can query related fields of article types when querying  Knowledge article version object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `KnowledgeArticleVersion` object to query for articles across all article types depending on their version.

Try this

```
SELECT Title, Summary FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus='Online' AND Language = 'en_US'
```

Refer [KnowledgeArticleVersion object in Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm)

Comment: I need custom fields from Help_Center__kav (ArticleType__kav object) and looks like there is no direct relationship between KnowledgeArticleVersion and ArticleType
So querying on KnowledgeArticleVersion won't help